# Map-reduce Concept

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What type of the inputs and outputs do the map and reduce functions in
MapReduce use? How are the inputs and outputs of the two functions connected?

The input of map function in MapReduce is a document

The output of map function in MapReduce is a sequence of tuple(word,1)

The input of reduce function in MapReduce is a key and a list of all values of that key

The output of reduce function in MapReduce is a sequence of tuples(word, number of occurrences)

Is it correct? what about the connected functions, is combiner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputs and outputs are connected via serialization.

The default input is `TextInputFormat` which uses a `LineRecordReader`, however both of these properties can be overridden

Underneath, everything is only bytes, and the Writable objects in MapReduce (Text, IntWritable, etc) are just thin layers over a `byte[]`

Reducer input is the joined output of a mapper, by key, yes. Output are key value pairs, or a tuple. But both values can be complex objects, so you output more than just two fields. A Combiner is just a different type Reducer.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps a lot